# Vaadin cannot find my theme files

Tags: java, css, sass, vaadin, vaadin8

I was just trying to do normal stuff when I got this error

```
INFO: Requested resource [/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/styles.css] not found from filesystem or through class loader. Add widgetset and/or theme JAR to your classpath or add files to WebContent/VAADIN folder.
```

Here is my [`styles.css`](https://pastebin.com/nknPJkBc)

My `addons.scss`

```
/* This file is automatically managed and will be overwritten from time to time. */
/* Do not manually edit this file. */

/* Import and include this mixin into your project theme to include the addon themes */
@mixin addons {
}
```

My `styles.scss`

```
@import "mytheme.scss";
@import "addons.scss";

// This file prefixes all rules with the theme name to avoid causing conflicts with other themes.
// The actual styles should be defined in mytheme.scss

.mytheme {
  @include addons;
  @include mytheme;

}
```

My `mytheme.scss`

```
// If you edit this file you need to compile the theme. See README.md for details.

// Global variable overrides. Must be declared before importing Valo.

// Defines the plaintext font size, weight and family. Font size affects general component sizing.
//$v-font-size: 16px;
//$v-font-weight: 300;
//$v-font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;

// Defines the border used by all components.
//$v-border: 1px solid (v-shade 0.7);
//$v-border-radius: 4px;

// Affects the color of some component elements, e.g Button, Panel title, etc
//$v-background-color: hsl(210, 0%, 98%);
// Affects the color of content areas, e.g  Panel and Window content, TextField input etc
//$v-app-background-color: $v-background-color;

// Affects the visual appearance of all components
//$v-gradient: v-linear 8%;
//$v-bevel-depth: 30%;
//$v-shadow-opacity: 5%;

// Defines colors for indicating status (focus, success, failure)
//$v-focus-color: valo-focus-color(); // Calculates a suitable color automatically
//$v-friendly-color: #2c9720;
//$v-error-indicator-color: #ed473b;

// For more information, see: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.valo.html
// Example variants can be copy/pasted from https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Valo+Examples

@import "../valo/valo.scss";

@mixin mytheme {
  @include valo;

  // Insert your own theme rules here
}
```

Oh and I am using Eclipse so [Vaadin can't find my themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157728/vaadin-cant-find-my-themes) wont help
Thanks

Comment: Your `mytheme.css` contains SASS? Or did you mean your `mytheme.scss`?

Comment: i meant mytheme.scss

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference but try the import line `@import "../valo/valo";`.

Comment: Are you sure the missing css file exists at the right location (or can be generated on the fly, so included theme compiler)? Or maybe a (servlet) filter is not correctly configured? Your scss file are okay btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my own answer for this by running

```
mvn package jetty:run
```

instead of

```
mvn jetty:run
```

which reset vaadins styles